# Linq group by specific fields then transform to dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a flat collection with some ratings details.

```
public class testClass
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public byte Rating { get; set; }
    public Int32 ReviewByRatingCount { get; set; }
    public Int32 TotalReviewsByRating { get; set; }
    public double AverageRating { get; set; }

}

var list = new List<testClass>
{
    new testClass { Label = "Model 3", TotalReviewsByRating = 38, AverageRating= 4.58, Rating = 5, ReviewByRatingCount =30},
    new testClass { Label = "Model 3", TotalReviewsByRating = 38, AverageRating= 4.58, Rating = 4, ReviewByRatingCount =5},
    new testClass { Label = "Model 3", TotalReviewsByRating = 38, AverageRating= 4.58, Rating = 1, ReviewByRatingCount =2},
    new testClass { Label = "Model 3", TotalReviewsByRating = 38, AverageRating= 4.58, Rating = 2, ReviewByRatingCount =1}
};
```

Have to transform the data like this.

```
{
    Label = "Model 3",
    TotalReviewsByRating = 38,
    AverageRating = 4.58,
    ReviewsByRatingCount = [{ "5" : 30 }, { "4" : 5 }, { "1" : 2 }, { "2" : 1 }]
}
```

I have achived that using multiple group by and use select statement to transform as a key value pairs. But I would like to konw,if there a better way to do that?

```
public class testClassDto
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,int> ReviewsByRatingCount { get; set; }
    public Int32 TotalReviewsByRating { get; set; }
    public double AverageRating { get; set; }

}

var data = list.GroupBy(p => new { p.Label , p.TotalReviewsByRating, p.AverageRating})
    .Select(group => new testClassDto 
    { 
        Label = group.Key.Label,                                                     
        TotalReviewsByRating = group.Key.TotalReviewsByRating,
        AverageRating = group.Key.AverageRating,                                     
        ReviewsByRatingCount = group.Select(s => new {s.Rating,s.ReviewByRatingCount})
            .ToDictionary(s => s.Rating.ToString(),s => s.ReviewByRatingCount)
    });
```

Comment: Better way? What part of the code seems unsatisfying or which possible improvement did you have in mind? All I see is you can skip the `.Select()` statement when you assign the value of `ReviewsByRatingCount` by doing `ReviewsByRatingCount = group.ToDictionary(s => s.Rating.ToString(),s => s.ReviewByRatingCount)`

Comment: Currently I have lot of fileds in the source collection, but I removed that for brevity. Becuase I dont like to create anynmous type with around 12 fileds. the above code I have added only three fields.

Comment: When generating the dictionary, the order should be defined by the value field (decending). but it is ordering my key field.

Comment: @Arooran dictionaries do not have a guaranteed order.  If you need the data in a particular order then you need something other than a dictionary.

Comment: Use Ordered Dictionary? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary?view=netframework-4.8